# Castle ActiveRecordMediator Key not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-3.5, castle-activerecord

I'm having problem moving from mvc 1 to mvc 2.
In my old project I used Active Record.

Now running on new project where trying to get data from reposetory

```
      public T[] SlicedFindAll(int firstResult, int maxResult, DetachedCriteria criteria)
  {
      return ActiveRecordMediator<T>.SlicedFindAll(firstResult, maxResult, criteria);
  }
```

I recive an error  "The given key was not present in the dictionary."

This is a stack trace:

[KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.]
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key) +9627953
   NHibernate.Cfg.Mapping.GetPersistentClass(String className) +85
   NHibernate.Cfg.Mapping.GetIdentifierType(String className) +66
   NHibernate.Type.EntityType.GetIdentifierType(IMapping factory) +84
   NHibernate.Type.EntityType.GetIdentifierOrUniqueKeyType(IMapping factory) +112
   NHibernate.Type.ManyToOneType.GetColumnSpan(IMapping mapping) +66
   NHibernate.Mapping.SimpleValue.IsValid(IMapping mapping) +96
   NHibernate.Mapping.ToOne.IsValid(IMapping mapping) +144
   NHibernate.Mapping.Property.IsValid(IMapping mapping) +80
   NHibernate.Mapping.PersistentClass.Validate(IMapping mapping) +138
   NHibernate.Mapping.RootClass.Validate(IMapping mapping) +68
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.ValidateEntities() +246
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.Validate() +44
   NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory() +86
   Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.SessionFactoryHolder.GetSessionFactory(Type type) in d:\Dev\Out\castleproject-Castle.ActiveRecord-b0f7972\castleproject-Castle.ActiveRecord-b0f7972\src\Castle.ActiveRecord\Framework\SessionFactoryHolder.cs:135
   Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.SessionFactoryHolder.CreateScopeSession(Type type) in d:\Dev\Out\castleproject-Castle.ActiveRecord-b0f7972\castleproject-Castle.ActiveRecord-b0f7972\src\Castle.ActiveRecord\Framework\SessionFactoryHolder.cs:296
   Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.SessionFactoryHolder.CreateSession(Type type) in d:\Dev\Out\castleproject-Castle.ActiveRecord-b0f7972\castleproject-Castle.ActiveRecord-b0f7972\src\Castle.ActiveRecord\Framework\SessionFactoryHolder.cs:182
   Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordBase.SlicedFindAll(Type targetType, Int32 firstResult, Int32 maxResults, Order[] orders, DetachedCriteria criteria) in d:\Dev\Out\castleproject-Castle.ActiveRecord-b0f7972\castleproject-Castle.ActiveRecord-b0f7972\src\Castle.ActiveRecord\Framework\ActiveRecordBase.cs:1420
   Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordMediator.SlicedFindAll(Type targetType, Int32 firstResult, Int32 maxResults, Order[] orders, DetachedCriteria criteria) in d:\Dev\Out\castleproject-Castle.ActiveRecord-b0f7972\castleproject-Castle.ActiveRecord-b0f7972\src\Castle.ActiveRecord\Framework\ActiveRecordMediator.cs:185
   Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordMediator`1.SlicedFindAll(Int32 firstResult, Int32 maxResults, DetachedCriteria criteria, Order[] orders) in d:\Dev\Out\castleproject-Castle.ActiveRecord-b0f7972\castleproject-Castle.ActiveRecord-b0f7972\src\Castle.ActiveRecord\Framework\ActiveRecordMediator.Generic.cs:241
   Cameos.Core.Persistence.Repository`1.SlicedFindAll(Int32 firstResult, Int32 maxResult, DetachedCriteria criteria) in d:\Dev\MVC2\Cameos\src\Cameos.Core\Persistence\Repository.cs:96
   Cameos.Core.Paging.PagedList`1..ctor(IRepository`1 repository, Int32 page, Int32 size, DetachedCriteria criteria) in d:\Dev\MVC2\Cameos\src\Cameos.Core\Paging\PagedList.cs:24
   Cameos.Core.Paging.PagedList`1.Create(IRepository`1 repository, Int32 page, Int32 pageSize, DetachedCriteria criteria) in d:\Dev\MVC2\Cameos\src\Cameos.Core\Paging\PagedList.cs:13
   Cameos.Core.Paging.PaginationHelpers.Paginate(IRepository`1 repository, Int32 startPage, Int32 pageSize, DetachedCriteria criteria) in d:\Dev\MVC2\Cameos\src\Cameos.Core\Paging\PaginationHelpers.cs:52
   Cameos.Core.Paging.PaginationHelpers.Paginate(IRepository`1 repository, Int32 startPage, Int32 pageSize, Order order, ICriterion[] criteria) in d:\Dev\MVC2\Cameos\src\Cameos.Core\Paging\PaginationHelpers.cs:34
   Cameos.Web.Areas.Admin.Controllers.CompanyController.Index(Nullable`1 page) in d:\Dev\MVC2\Cameos\src\Cameos.Web2\Areas\Admin\Controllers\CompanyController.cs:26
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +145
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +409
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClassd.b*_a() +127
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +436
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassf.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__c() +61
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +436
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClassf.b*_c() +61
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +305
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +830
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +111
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass8.b*_4() +65
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c_*DisplayClass1.b*_0() +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +141
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8836913
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184

Comment: Could you provide criteria that caused error?

Comment: You seem to have a misconfigured [BelongsTo]... can you post your activerecord classes? Also, this is not related to mvc

Comment: Thanks Mauricio my head was to lazy to go over classes again. I set wrong BelongsTo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `[BelongsTo]` is misconfigured.